# How do I add numbers on top of my bar graph (google chats)

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

H

I want to add numbers a top a bar graph using the goole chart api

[what I want](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=150x100&chbh=15,10&chd=t2:10,20,30,20,70,80|20,10,5,20,30,10|10,0,20,15,60,40,30&chds=0,120&chco=224499,009900&chm=D,76A4FB,2,0,3|N,FF0000,-1,-1,10)

That is what I want. It is an example from the [home page](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). When I look at the options for  [bar charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html)  I don't see it. I am not sure what it would be called but nothing I see looks like it(at least not from the example pictures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "|N,FF0000,-1,-1,10"
 on the above URL is the magic sauce that makes it work.

The [Text and Data Value Markers](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_params.html#gcharts_data_point_labels) documentation explains:

`chm=<marker_type>,<color>,<series_index>,<opt_which_points>,<size>,<opt_z_order>,<opt_placement>`.

Where `<marker_type>` in this case, is `N`.

Comment: @ohn Gietzen - Ok I see. I guess the next question is what one would it be in this plugin? http://keith-wood.name/gChartRef.html#markers I not sure which of these choices I should be passing in. I am thinking placement but I am not sure how to pass it in.

Comment: @chobo2: You would use something like `$.gchart.marker('number', 'black')`.

Comment: @ John Gietzen - Ya I i just fgured it out but what I am finding it only labels one bar. I want it to label every bar. I thought if I put 0 that would go to N but that does not seem to be the case. I also tried -1 but same thing.

Comment: @chobo2: Well, if you want to label more than one series, you either use -1 for the series number, or you add more instances of the marker, one for each series.

Comment: I tried   markers: [$.gchart.marker('number', 'red', -1,-1)] I want to go to N to I thought -1 would do it but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: @chobo2: You might want to post that as a separate question, tagged with the gChart tag.

Comment: @John Gietzen - Ya probably would be better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047947/how-to-label-my-bar-chart-with-numbers