# How to label my bar chart with numbers?

Tags: jquery-plugins, google-api, google-visualization, gchart

I am using [gchart](http://keith-wood.name/gChart.html) and I am trying to use markers to label my bar char with numbers. So that ever bar has a number value on top of it.

I tried

```
markers: [$.gchart.marker('number', 'red', -1)]
markers: [$.gchart.marker('number', 'red', -1, -1)]
markers: [$.gchart.marker('number', 'red', -1, 'every')]
markers: [$.gchart.marker('number', 'red', -1, 'every1')]
```

I can only make it appear on the one bar. I want it to show up on every bar.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

See it has no label on the first one.

```
https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=400x500&cht=bvg&chd=t:55|47&chco=FDFF0F,1FEEFF&chm=N,ff0000,-1,-1,10,0&chdl=test2|test1&chdlp=b|l&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|atest

 $('#id').gchart({
                        type: 'barVertGrouped',
                        markers: [$.gchart.marker('number', 'red',-1)],
                        height: 500,
                        width: 400,
                        series: data, // xml data from server.
                        legend: 'bottom',
                        extension: { chxt: 'x,y', chxl: '0:|atest' }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-stacked bar graphs, you need to add a marker per series:

```
$('#id').gchart({
    type: 'barVertGrouped',
    markers: [
        $.gchart.marker('number', 'red',0),
        $.gchart.marker('number', 'blue',1)
    ],
    height: 500,
    width: 400,
    series: [
        $.gchart.series('test1', [47], 'blue'),
        $.gchart.series('test2', [60], 'red')
    ],
    legend: 'bottom',
    extension: { chxt: 'x,y', chxl: '0:|atest' }
});
```